# Running jQuery in Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby, execjs

I want to run jQuery in a Ruby application and use it to manipulate an HTML string. (Yes, I know there are other Ruby libraries that can handle that task, but I have a good reason for using jQuery in this case.) Is this possible? I know that I can use ExecJS to execute simple JavaScript code in my Ruby application, but jQuery doesn't seem to be working:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'execjs'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'open-uri'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> context = ExecJS.compile(open("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js").read)
=> <Return omitted for brevity>
irb(main):004:0> context.call("$", "<div>Test</div>")
ExecJS::ProgramError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:19:in `eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:33:in `call'
        from (irb):4
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Ajedi I'm trying to do something similar and asked this question: [Sharing business logic between server-side and client-side of web application?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/202567/sharing-business-logic-between-server-side-and-client-side-of-web-application/202586?noredirect=1#202586) Let me know what you found out!

Comment: @thoughtpunch Unfortunately I haven't taken the time to get much further on this one.

What I *want* to do is create a sort of MVC library that runs both client and server-side on a Rails application, so I can take advantage of lightning-fast AJAX-based page loads and dynamic JavaScript animations when the user has JavaScript enabled but still have everything work when they don't (or when Googlebot comes along). I have a few ideas on how I might be able to get this working but nothing solid just yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

jQuery is a library for DOM manipulation. It expects to see all of the usual DOM objects and interfaces, including the `window` object.

The ExecJS library you're using doesn't provide a DOM or a `window` object. It provides a JavaScript execution context, but not the same one a browser provides.

You may possibly be able to get this working by using another library such as [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to provide a DOM that jQuery can use. Here is [a search that may give some tips](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+execjs+jquery+window).

The first link describes a [use of JSDOM and jQuery with ExecJS](http://blog.envylabs.com/post/29003944783/running-jquery-code-from-ruby-using-execjs-async) that may be similar to what you want.

That said, why jQuery? There are several good [Ruby HTML parsers](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+html+parser) including [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). Why not try one of those?

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I'm looking for. The reason I want to use jQuery is pretty complicated. Basically, I need an interface compatible with [opal-jquery](https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery) so that I can use the same code to manipulate the DOM both client and server-side. That't the idea anyway.

Answer (score -4):

You can't run jQuery in Ruby. jQuery isn't written in Ruby, it's in JavaScript so you'll need to run a JavaScript interpreter to use it.

Comment: Uh, yeah. But I can run other JavaScript code with ExecJS. Why not jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is written to work on DOM which you can't get in server side. But I'm sure you can use it's utility methods like `$.each` in server side.

Comment: No, once I load jQuery I can't even evaluate 1 + 1 without getting this error.